# Removal of metadata added by feed

Tags: google-search-appliance

I have a GSA that fulfils a number of roles within my organisation. Honestly it's a bit of a frankenmess but it's what I have to work with.

One of the things we have it doing is indexing a number of sites based on a feed we pass it. Each of the items we pass in the feed gets tagged with a metadata that allows me to setup a frontend that only queries those items. This is working fine for the most part except that now I want to *remove* some metadata from items that are in the index (thereby stopping them from being in that particular frontend) and I can't figure out how.

I use a metadata-and-url type feed to push in these urls I want the system to be aware of. But it also finds a number of them through standard indexing patterns.

Heres the issue. The items that are in the index that have been found as a part of the standard crawling I can't remove. I just need the GSA to forget that I ever attached metadata to them.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can push a new feed that either updates the metadata or deletes the individual records that you want to remove from your frontend.

You can also block specific results from appearing in a specific frontend as a temporary measure while you work it out. See [this doco](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/76/admin_console_help/serve_remove.html).

It sounds like you would be better off using [collections](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/76/admin_console_help/crawl_collections.html) to group the subsets of the index that you want to present in a specific frontend.